# GCD algorithms for arbitrary-precision arithmetic

Tags: c, algorithm, gmp, arbitrary-precision, greatest-common-divisor

I am completely stuck with this question, so I am looking for any help.

I think everybody knows about basic GCD computation algorithms like binary or euclidean GCD. It is not a problem to implement such a method to compute two single-precision numbers. Actually, it's just about couple of strokes.

I need to have this method implemented (in C language) for multiple-precision numbers (more than 10^5 bits). There are couple of GNU libraries available (GNU MP, MPFR, MPIR) and they have means to define multiple-precision numbers and make an actions on them. It looks like one multiple-precision number stored in memory as couple of single-precision parts aka "limbs".

The have some methods implemented for finding gcd(a, b), but they, actually, difficult to use for my needs. Binary method for GCD computation used only when a and b contains exactly two limbs. HGCD method used when min(a,b) contains more than (i.e. 630) limbs, etc.
I find difficult to figure out, how any of these methods could be expanded for using with any length of a and b. I've also found that different version of GNU libraries contains different versions and methods of GCD algorithms.

**Question:** I want to find out is it possible to make the binary GCD algorithm works with multiple-precision integers of any length in terms of "limbs", and if it possible - to get any help or ideas how to implement it in C. Does anyone have any idea or code parts how to implement it?

I'd like to consider any advice or any other solution to solve that problem.

Here is the part of GNU MP binary GCD method for (a = b = 2 limbs) if anyone would take a look:

```
/* Use binary algorithm to compute G <-- GCD (U, V) for usize, vsize == 2.
   Both U and V must be odd. */
static inline mp_size_t
gcd_2 (mp_ptr gp, mp_srcptr up, mp_srcptr vp)
{
  printf("gcd_2 invoked\n");
  mp_limb_t u0, u1, v0, v1;
  mp_size_t gn;

  u0 = up[0];
  u1 = up[1];
  v0 = vp[0];
  v1 = vp[1];

  ASSERT (u0 & 1);
  ASSERT (v0 & 1);

  /* Check for u0 != v0 needed to ensure that argument to
   * count_trailing_zeros is non-zero. */
  while (u1 != v1 && u0 != v0)
    {
      unsigned long int r;
      if (u1 > v1)
  {
    sub_ddmmss (u1, u0, u1, u0, v1, v0);
    count_trailing_zeros (r, u0);
    u0 = ((u1 << (GMP_NUMB_BITS - r)) & GMP_NUMB_MASK) | (u0 >> r);
    u1 >>= r;
  }
      else  /* u1 < v1.  */
  {
    sub_ddmmss (v1, v0, v1, v0, u1, u0);
    count_trailing_zeros (r, v0);
    v0 = ((v1 << (GMP_NUMB_BITS - r)) & GMP_NUMB_MASK) | (v0 >> r);
    v1 >>= r;
  }
    }

  gp[0] = u0, gp[1] = u1, gn = 1 + (u1 != 0);

  /* If U == V == GCD, done.  Otherwise, compute GCD (V, |U - V|).  */
  if (u1 == v1 && u0 == v0)
    return gn;

  v0 = (u0 == v0) ? ((u1 > v1) ? u1-v1 : v1-u1) : ((u0 > v0) ? u0-v0 : v0-u0);
  gp[0] = mpn_gcd_1 (gp, gn, v0);

  return 1;
}
```

[CodePaste of the above](http://codepaste.ru/13601/).

Comment: Are you implementing your own? Otherwise, `void mpz_gcd (mpz_t ROP, mpz_t OP1, mpz_t OP2)` seems easy enough to use.

Comment: Since the complexity of binary GCD algorithm is O(N^2), I would like to have the code with the same complexity if it possible. I know, this code will not be really efficient if compared to any subquadratic algorithms for large integers. The point of my work is just to show how bad the clean binary algorithm will be with multiple-precision numbers compared to any other solutions.

Comment: `void mpz_gcd (mpz_t ROP, mpz_t OP1, mpz_t OP2)`

If I set the OP1 = (10^5 bits) and OP2 = (10^5 bits) then this method will compute gcd using improved "Shonhage's" algorithm. But I want to compute this number using clean binary algorithm to compare procedure execution time to know how poor the efficient of Binary GCD. Hope that this is possible to do.

Comment: Okay, you can of course implement the binary GCD algorithm for arbitrary precision numbers pretty much like for standard machine types. If you're using GMP, `mpz_tdiv_q_2exp` is your bit-shift. Otherwise, writing a bit-shift for an array is simple if it need not be very efficient.

Comment: @DanielFischer, this is probably the way I should go (I'm using GMP). It seems I've got the idea, thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you still can do that with `gmp's gcd` but you will have to compile it from scratch having changed some values from the `gmp-mparam.h` file. There are a couple that refer to thresholds of the gcd algorithm.

Comment: I've tried to dig in GMP source code, but unfortunately, there is not much to do with thresholds. I've using GMP 5.1 and there is only one THRESHOLD (GCD_DC_THRESHOLD) to change, and it's not helping too much. It's anyway try to use HGCD in any cases when length of min(a,b) > 2, because as I understand it, this is a kind of default method to compute gcd.

Comment: I think this could be a way. I'll try to imitate the usual algorithm steps (Euclid and Binary) just for multiple-precision numbers using different GMP functions thinking as they just usual single-precision. It will be really slow for big numbers but it's exactly what I want. I'll try to do that but any comments are welcome anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just roll your own code specifically for this problem, why not? `(10^9)^2` fits into 64-bit int, so you can work with **base-`(10^9)` digits**, each held in a 64-bit int. To represent `2^(10^5)`-bits values, `2^(10^5) ~= 10^30103`, i.e. values with ~ 30103 decimal digits, you will only need  `30103/9 ~= 3350` ints which is a ~ 27 kB array in memory, for each of the two numbers involved.

[According to WP, for binary GCD algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm#Algorithm) you only need `minus` and `/2` which is trivial to implement by halving each digit, with occasional carry of `5*10^8` into the lower digit `(94 / 2 = 47 = {4,5+2})`. The final multiply by **2<sup>*k*</sup>** can be done with a naive algorithm, since it needs to be done only once.

Printing in base-`10` will be trivial. If you don't care for the printing of the final result, then you won't need the final multiply (or if you report your result as `2^k*x`) and you could then work with base-`10^18` digits, halving the number of digits to work with.

You will only need the usual C integer arithmetic to work with the digits.

Comment: Could you please share some short examples or links how to work with numbers (in C) with some other "base" than 10? How this abstraction should looks like. Thanks.

Comment: {A,B} + {C,D} : N1=B+C; R1=N1 % base; Carry=N1 / base; N2 = A+C+Carry; R2=N2 % base; Carry=N2 / base; if (Carry > 0) then Result = {Carry,R2,R1} else Result = {R2,R1} . Do this with a loop; represent lists of digits by arrays + number_of_digits.

Comment: @MikhailKalashnikov  correction: N1 = B+D, of course. Operations on each pair of digits are done with regular int operations. For this not to cause overflow, max_digit^2 must be less than int range (if we multiply). If we only add/subtract, max_digit*2 must be < int range (MAXINT).